# Difference in mean frequency in Python and Matlab

Tags: python, matlab, signal-processing, fft, mean

I have this [EMG signal](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o8gklajv6curjqv/EMG.txt?dl=0) and I would like to plot the mean power frequency based on this [article](http://biorobotics.snu.ac.kr/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/The-Usefulness-of-Mean-and-Median-Frequencies-in-Electromyography-Analysis.pdf?ckattempt=1). I implement it in Matlab using the following code:

```
clear all;
close all;
EMG=load('EMG.txt');
N=1000; %my window 
z=1;
fs=200 %sampling rate
for i=1:length(EMG)-N
     DUM=0;
     NUM=0;
     FT=fft(EMG(i:i+N-1));
     psd=FT.*conj(FT);
     NFFT=length(fft2);
     f = [1:NFFT/2]*fs/N;
     for j=1:NFFT/2
         NUM=NUM+f(j)*psd(j);
         DUM=DUM+psd(j);
     end
     MPF(z)=NUM/DUM;
     z=z+1;
 end
```

And the plot of MPF is:

[image: MPF using Matlab]

Following I am trying to do the same in Python. The code is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('EMG.txt', names=['EMG'])
EMG=df['EMG'].tolist()
sampling_rate=200
N=1000 #my window
FT=np.fft.fft(EMG, axis=0)
psd=FT*np.conj(FT)
NFFT=len(FT)
f =(np.arange(0,NFFT/2)*sampling_rate)/N
NUM=0
DUM=0
MPF=[]
for j in np.arange(1,NFFT/2):
    NUM=NUM+f[j]*psd[j]
    DUM=DUM+psd[i]
    MPF.append(NUM/DUM)

plt.plot(MPF)        
plt.show()
```

And the plot of the MPF is:
[image: MPF using Python]

Why are different?

### **Update**

Following the advice of Dan at the comment section I modify my Python code as follow and the results more or less the same, except that the Matlab code is way faster than Python which in my case was running out of memory:

```
sampling_rate=200
N=1000
MPF=[]
for i in range(0,len(EMG)-N):
    signal=EMG[i:(i+N)]
    FT=np.fft.fft(signal, axis=0)
    psd=FT*np.conj(FT)
    NFFT=len(FT)
    f =(np.arange(0,NFFT/2)*sampling_rate)/N
    D_1=0
    N_1=0
    for j in np.arange(1,NFFT/2):
       D_1=D_1+f[j]*psd[j]
       N_1=N_1+psd[j]   
       MPF.append(D_1/N_1)

plt.plot(MPF)        
plt.show()
```

Choosing the first 22000 samples the results are:
[image: Matlab]
[image: Python]

Comment: What happened to your outer `for` loop in the Python code? In MATLAB you are windowing the data here `FT=fft(EMG(i:i+N-1));` but in Python it looks like you're taking the fft of all the data `FT=np.fft.fft(EMG, axis=0)`... Also you are indexing your variables with the same integers in both languages but MATLAB uses 1-based indexing and Python uses 0-based indexing so surely you have a lot of off by one errors due to that?

Comment: Incidentally, `MPF.append(NUM/DUM)` could be written as `MPF(end+1) = NUM/DUM;` in MATLAB so you don't need the `z` counter variable...

Comment: @Dan First of all thanks. I edited my code but when I am running it, I also run out of memory. Can you please run it if possible. Here it is:
for i in range(0,len(EMG)-N):
    FT=np.fft.fft(EMG[i:(i+N)],axis=0)
    psd=FT*np.conj(FT)
    NFFT=len(FT)
    f =(np.arange(0,NFFT/2)*sampling_rate)/N
    #N_1=np.zeros(NFFT/2)
    D_1=0
    N_1=0
    MPF=[]
    for j in np.arange(1,NFFT/2):
        D_1=D_1+f[j]*psd[j]
        N_1=N_1+psd[j]
    MPF.append(D_1/N_1)

Comment: (1) don't post code in the comments, edit your question to add code. (2) If you're running out of memory, I suggest that you first test it on a smaller dataset. Make a copy of your `EMG.txt` file and reduce it to say 10% of it's original size and then test the two scripts on that.

Comment: One reason your code is probably so slow is because you are converting your dataframe to a list.  This duplicates the data, and doing this sort of thing with lists is much slower.  For very simple data like this `numpy.fromfile` will be sufficient, and will give you a numpy array.  You can also do `df['EMG'].values` to get a numpy array.  MPF should also be a numpy array of zeros.  The calculation of D_1 and F_1 can be vectorized.  And don't use `arange` for loop indexes, use `range`, or better yet (if you can't vectorize) do `for fj, psdj in zip(f, psd)` (or `izip` in python 2).

Answer (score 1):

'detrend' option would cause the difference of the first value (0 Hz or DC).

The default setting is 'constant', which removes DC component from the original data.

```
f, Pxx_den = signal.periodogram(x, fs, detrend=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going on with this question and answer.

1) In Matlab, try to use the built-in function `meanfreq`, and `medfreq` will also help you to find the median frequency.

2) Until now, I have not found a package to solve the mean/median frequency with Python.

3) I also tried to solve the mean/median frequency with Python. 
And I follow the computation steps in Matlab `meanfreq`. (In Matlab command windows, type `edit meanfreq.m`, you could see the source code of `meanfreq`. The source code would help a lot.

4) The following is my python-based implementation of `meanfreq`

```
from scipy import signal

def meanfreq(x, fs):
    f, Pxx_den = signal.periodogram(x, fs)                                                    
    Pxx_den = np.reshape( Pxx_den, (1,-1) ) 
    width = np.tile(f[1]-f[0], (1, Pxx_den.shape[1]))
    f = np.reshape(f, (1, -1))
    P = Pxx_den * width
    pwr = np.sum(P)

    mnfreq = np.dot(P, f.T)/pwr

    return mnfreq
```

5) You can debug these source code of both mine and Matlab.

6) There is also a small 'bug' in my code, or not mine. When you debug them, you may find the first (only the first value) of Pxx is totally different. The rest of values are identical. 
**I am also very confused here. Help me.** :)