# How to compute Dimitrov spectral fatigue index in Python?

Tags: python, frequency-analysis

I have an already existing python script to calculate mean power frequency. Additionally I would like to calculate dimitrovs spectral fatigue index. Its formula slightly differs from mean power frequency  instead of using a ratio of the moments of 1 and 0 it uses the moments of -1 and 5. I thought, I could simply add the moments of interest, but I get only inf-values in the renamed FInms5 function

[[mean power frequency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fU3qO.png)]
[[dimitrov spectral fatigue index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BOsm.png)]

This is the working mean freq function. I changed the last line to:
mean_freq[i] = np.dot(P,f.t**-1)/np.dot(P,f.t**5)

from scipy.signal import periodogram

def get_mean_freq(emg_sig, sfreq, epoch_duration = 0.5):
'''
Parameters
----------
emg_sig : array
pre-filtered emg data.
sfreq : int
emg sampling frequency, in Hz.
epoch_duration : float
epoch (time window) duration, in seconds.

```
Returns
-------
mean_freq: array
    mean frequency at each epoch
time_points: array
    time point at the center of each evaluated epoch
samples: array
    sample numbers at the center of each evaluated epoch

Method according to:
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37922928/difference-in-mean-frequency-in-python-and-matlab
'''
ons = range(
    0,
    len(emg_sig),
    int(epoch_duration*sfreq)
    )

mean_freq = np.empty((len(ons),))
samples =np.empty((len(ons),))
time_points = np.empty((len(ons),))
for i,on in enumerate(ons):# i,on = 0,ons[0]
    off = ons[i+1]-1 if i+1<len(ons) else len(emg_sig)
    # print([on,off])
    processing_window = emg_sig[on:off]
    mid_point = (on + off) / 2
    samples[i] = mid_point
    # t_epoch[ch] += [mid_point / sfreq]
    time_points[i] = mid_point / sfreq
    # Processing window power spectrum (PSD) generation
    f, Pxx_den = periodogram(np.array(processing_window), fs=float(sfreq))# plot_freq_spectrum(f, Pxx_den)
    Pxx_den = np.reshape(Pxx_den, (1,-1))
    width = np.tile(f[2]-f[0], (1, Pxx_den.shape[2]))
    f = np.reshape(f, (1,-1))
    P = Pxx_den*width
    pwr = np.sum(P)
    mean_freq[i] = np.dot(P, f.T)/pwr

return mean_freq, time_points, samples
```

This is the working mean freq function. I changed the last line to:
mean_freq[i] = np.dot(P,f.t**-1)/np.dot(P,f.t**5)

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/He32L.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6gGD.png
```

Comment: This question should include sample data which produces the error identified, along with what steps have been taken to diagnose the problem together with the results of such effort.

Comment: Hi itprorh66, sample data is an array of up to 200000 floating numbers. As it is not an error but inf-values I get, I haven't done any diagnosis steps so far.

Comment: 200000 data points is not sample data that is the data, this site isn't here to perform debug for you, you need to do the work before asking the question.  Can you at least correlate the inf-values to data points, to narrow the search for the issue?